# Using an implicit assumption to simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

How can I simplify below expression knowing that `r12>>z`? Is there any way to expand below expression?

```
-(1/(128 eta \[Pi] r12^3 z^3))(-6 r12^4 z Cos[the] + 
   4 H r12 (-2 r12^3 + z^3) Cos[the - tp] + 
   12 H r12 z^3 Cos[3 the + tp] + 4 r12^5 Sin[2 the] + 
   6 H^2 z^3 Sin[2 the] - 8 r12^2 z^3 Sin[2 the] + 
   6 H r12^3 z Sin[tp] + 4 H^2 r12^3 Sin[2 tp] + H^2 z^3 Sin[2 tp] + 
   15 H^2 z^3 Sin[4 the + 2 tp])
```

Comment: How about `Series[%, {z, 0, 1}]`,  which assumes that `z` is small.  Alternative expansions might be more appropriate, depending on the relative magnitude of the other variables.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. You received two answers a week ago. While it's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time and wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one, one week is enough wait. Participation, that includes [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq) and  [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD),  is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is a rational function of `z` so that `Series` won't actually do anything to it. To check this, define the given expression as

```
expr = -(1/(128 eta Pi r12^3 z^3)) (-6 r12^4 z Cos[the] + 
    4 H r12 (-2 r12^3 + z^3) Cos[the - tp] + 
    12 H r12 z^3 Cos[3 the + tp] + 4 r12^5 Sin[2 the] + 
    6 H^2 z^3 Sin[2 the] - 8 r12^2 z^3 Sin[2 the] + 
    6 H r12^3 z Sin[tp] + 4 H^2 r12^3 Sin[2 tp] + H^2 z^3 Sin[2 tp] + 
    15 H^2 z^3 Sin[4 the + 2 tp])
```

And then check that it's already in the form that `Series` would produce by itself:

```
Simplify[expr == Normal@Series[expr, {z, 0, 1}]]
```

> `True`

You could make a list of the powers of `z` appearing in the expression and decide which of the powers can be neglected by inspecting the coefficients:

```
Expand@SeriesCoefficient[expr, {z, 0, n}]
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  \frac{3 \text{r12} \cos (\text{the})}{64 \pi  \eta }-\frac{3 H \sin (\text{tp})}{64 \pi 
>    \eta } & n=-2 \\
>  -\frac{H^2 \sin (2 \text{tp})}{32 \pi  \eta }+\frac{H \text{r12} \cos
>    (\text{the}-\text{tp})}{16 \pi  \eta }-\frac{\text{r12}^2 \sin (2 \text{the})}{32 \pi 
>    \eta } & n=-3 \\
>  -\frac{15 H^2 \sin (4 \text{the}+2 \text{tp})}{128 \pi  \eta  \text{r12}^3}-\frac{3 H^2
>    \sin (2 \text{the})}{64 \pi  \eta  \text{r12}^3}-\frac{H^2 \sin (2 \text{tp})}{128 \pi
> \eta  \text{r12}^3}-\frac{H \cos (\text{the}-\text{tp})}{32 \pi  \eta 
>    \text{r12}^2}-\frac{3 H \cos (3 \text{the}+\text{tp})}{32 \pi  \eta 
>    \text{r12}^2}+\\+\frac{\sin (2 \text{the})}{16 \pi  \eta  \text{r12}} & n=0
> \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `z<<tp` just substitute `z->eps tp` in your expression

```
expr=-(1/(128 eta \[Pi] r12^3 z^3))(-6 r12^4 z Cos[the] + 
4 H r12 (-2 r12^3 + z^3) Cos[the - tp] + 
12 H r12 z^3 Cos[3 the + tp] + 4 r12^5 Sin[2 the] + 
6 H^2 z^3 Sin[2 the] - 8 r12^2 z^3 Sin[2 the] + 
6 H r12^3 z Sin[tp] + 4 H^2 r12^3 Sin[2 tp] + H^2 z^3 Sin[2 tp] +15 H^2 z^3   Sin[4 the + 2 tp]) /. z->eps tp ;
```

series expansion relating to eps gives

```
seps = Normal[Series[expr, {eps, 0,-2(*examplary*)}]] /.eps -> z/tp
(*(3 (r12 Cos[the] - H Sin[tp]))/(64 eta \[Pi] z^2) + (2 H r12 Cos[the - tp]- r12^2 Sin[2 the] - H^2 Sin[2 tp])/(32 eta \[Pi] z^3)*)
```

the approximation you are looking for.